# Trouble displaying two modules correctly. Both use modernizr library

Tags: magento-1.9

http://snowcoredev.co.uk/magento/

The menu and item slider seem to render correctly in full screen, but as soon as you scale down to the mobile view, the menu stops producing subcategories.

I have tried to establish which file causes the problem, and it looks like the modernizr library is at fault (removing it from the slidebar xml declaration fixes the problem, but breaks the slider obviously). I've noticed that my theme (modified 'rwd') already loads one instance of the library. I tried removing one or the other, but it removes my menu completely, or breaks the slider as mentioned before.

I'm trying to establish how to use both modules together, but I don't have any experience with modernizr, so I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are working to allow multiple versions of modernizr at once, but in the mean time what you would want to do is create a new build that has all the detects from both files.

Comment: Thanks alot @Patrick, that's super helpful. The two files have their differances (functions come with different parameter sets), but they both have the same version. If I build a single modernizr library, won't that screw up my other scripts?

How would I go about building my own library? Would that be just by going to [link](http://modernizr.com/) and configuring a build?

Comment: I have managed to build a new library, with virtually all tests possible, and it worked straight away! Now only to determine which ones I need, but that's just cosmetic. You've been great help Patrick, thanks!